# SQL UDF - Struct Diff

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a table with 2 top level columns of type 'struct' - one is a 'before', and an 'after' image.  The struct schemas are non trivial - nested, with arrays to a variable depth.  The are sent to us from replication, so the schemas are always the same (but the schemas of course can be updated at some point, but always together)

Objective is for the two input structs, to return 2 struct 'diffs' of the before and after with only fields that have changed - essentially the 'delta' diff of the changes produce by the replication source.  We know something has changed, but not 'what' since we get the full before and after image.  this raw data lands in BQ and is then processed from there but need to determine the more granular change for high order BQ processing.

The table schema is very wide (1000's of leaf fields), and the data populated fairly spare (so alot of nulls will be present on both sides of the snapshot) - so would need to be performant as best as possible when executing over 10s of millions of rows.

All things are nullable for maximum flexibility.

So change could look like:

- null -> value
- value -> null
- valueA -> valueB

Arrays:

recursive use of above for arrays of structs, ordering could be relaxed if that makes it easier?

It might not be possible.

Ive not attempted this yet as it seems really difficult so am looking to the community boffins for some support for this.  I feel the arrays could be difficult part.  There is probably an easy way perhaps in Python I dont or even doing some JSON conversion and comparison using JOSN tools?  It feels like it would be a super cool feature built in to BQ as well, so if can get this to work, will add a feature request for it.

Id like to have a SQL UDF for reuse (we have SQL skills not python, although if easier in python then thats ok), and now with the new feature of persistent SQL UDFs, this seems the right time to ask and test the feature out!

sql
def struct_diff(before Struct, after Struct)

(beforeChange, afterChange) - type of signature but open to suggestions?

Comment: This is an interesting question but probably not best suited for BQ.  I would consider Python to solve this problem.  Export (or query your table) as JSON, then loop through each row seeing if `before` and `after` are equal.  If not, then use a custom function to determine mismatches.  Unnesting 1000s of fields sounds painful; using Python libraries specifically built for JSON sounds like a better route.  Ultimately, if you can go to the source of record (ie, the system that is populating these tables), perhaps you can capture the changes there before it gets to your table.

Comment: Hey thanks - yeah felt a bit like Python (UDF) could be best, but python is out of my pay grade.  We get the changes from source, but we get the before and after full snapshots, so determining what actually changed (amongst the noise) is ultimately what I need.  Thanks for replying!

Comment: A BQ built in 'row_diff' function of course what be amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be really difficult to get a piece of reusable code. Since currently there is no support for recursive functions for SQL UDF, you cannot use a recursive approach for the nested structs.

[image: Invalid recursive definition]

Although, you might be able to get some specific SQL UDF functions depending on your array and structs structures. You can use an approach like this one to compare the structs.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION final_compare(s1 ANY TYPE, s2 ANY TYPE) AS (
  STRUCT(s1 as prev, s2 as cur)
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION compare(s1 ANY TYPE, s2 ANY TYPE) AS (
  STRUCT(final_compare(s1.structA, s2.structA))  
);
```

You can use `UNNEST` to [work with arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#querying-nested-arrays), and the final SQL UDF would really depend on your data.

As @rtenha suggested, Python could be a lot easier to handle this problem.

Finally, I did some tests using JavaScript UDF, and it was basically the same result, if not worst than SQL UDF.

The console allows a recursive definition of the function, however it will fail during execution. Also, javascript [doesn't allow the `ANY TYPE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#sql-type-encodings-in-javascript) data type on the signature, so you would have to define the whole STRUCT definition or use a workaround like applying [`TO_JSON_STRING`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#to_json_string) to your struct in order to pass it as a string.

Comment: Thanks for replying I missed this!  Does seem its nit really possible to do it elegently at the moment, unless someone else from BQ team knows better as they tend to.  Appreciated.